# Are there other known continued fractions that show the digits of the golden ratio?

Tags: number-theory

I found a few.
{16; 5, 1, 1, 5, 22}

{161; 1, 4, 11, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 13, 8, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 2, 1, 3, 8, 1, 2, 19, 1, 54, 1, 19, 2, 1, 8, 3, 1, 2, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1, 8, 13, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 11, 4, 1, 222}

{1618; 29, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5,...1, 2, 139, 2, 1...5, 2, 1, 2, 2, 29, 2236} 'to long

{16180; 2, 1, 16, 3, 2, 55, 3, 136,...2, 1, 1, 5589, 1, 1, 2...136, 3, 55, 2, 3, 16, 1, 2, 
22360}  'to long

My questions are why are the terms symmetrical with a central term, and why are we seeing the digits of the square root of 5 as the end term.
They are beautiful CF's.

Comment: Those are the continued fraction expansions of $10^k\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Comment: Read up on continued fractions.  This symmetry is common when the number has a square-root in it.  Nice observation about the final numbers though.